# Azure SQL DataSync ##MS_SyncAccount## missing

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-sync

The automatic sync from my syncgroups stopped in SQL Azure DB.

Running the health check script provided by Azure one of the warnings mentioned that **##MS_SyncAccount##** is missing.

I tried to create it as below...

```
CREATE USER [##MS_SyncAccount##]
GO
```

but I got the error message below

> '##MS_SyncAccount##' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.

The question here is how to create the **'##MS_SyncAccount##'** account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with your code I got the same error.

```
CREATE USER [##MS_SyncAccount##]
GO
```

Here is the reference image for error I got:

[image]

I tried this code and it is working for me.

```
CREATE USER [##MS_SyncAccount##]
WITHOUT LOGIN
GO
```

Here is the reference image for the same.

[image]

Reference below image to create the USER.

[image]